# Free search on multiple tables using JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a DB of Students who have a fullname, a location, and a list of schools they frequented.

"student" table

```
id | fullname | location
------------------------
```

"location" table

```
id | zipcode | city
-------------------
```

"school" table

```
id | name
---------
```

"student_school" table (which holds two foreign keys on school and user to create for each user a list of schools)

```
id | id_student | id_school
---------------------------
```

I want to perform a search through the students comparing the search term with student.fullname, location.zipcode, location.city, school.name and return all the students matching one (or more) of these conditions.
Note that student can have a null location, so we need an extern join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example of matching based on regular expressions:

```
  SELECT distinct s.id, s.fullname
  FROM student_school ss
       JOIN student s ON s.id = ss.id_student
       LEFT JOIN LOCATION l ON s.LOCATION = l.id
       JOIN school sc ON ss.id_school = sc.id
  WHERE  (s.fullname RLIKE 'Sasha.*') or 
         (ifnull(l.zipcode RLIKE '100.*', 0)) or
         (ifnull(l.city RLIKE 'New.*', 0)) or
         (sc.name RLIKE '.*2')
```

And here is complete [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26b36d/4)

So the general idea is to join all student data, filter rows matching at least one criterion and use distinct to group data and avoid duplicating of results.

**Update:**

To include students with no school records you may use following FROM phrase:

```
student_school ss
RIGHT JOIN student s ON s.id = ss.id_student
LEFT JOIN LOCATION l ON s.LOCATION = l.id
LEFT JOIN school sc ON ss.id_school = sc.id
```

Comment: Thanks, but there's a problem, if a student did not frequented any school, then it won't work. Consider this scheme: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25caf/1
Here our search is "sasha", but Sasha is not anymore registered as a former student of a known school. We should find her because of her name but we don't.

Comment: What if I would like to perform a search over another criteria separated into three tables (like schools here). Let's say if I want to perform the same search but I want my request to search through the companies the student have worked for (with table "companies", "student_companies" and "student") ? I mean will my SQL query work since "student s" has already been declared in a join ?

Comment: you can combine results of two queries via UNION keyword. It will also take care of removing duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get what I want using outer joins.
Will about the perfs of UNION keyword?